# Fusion table filter

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I can't for the life of me find what's wrong with my checkbox filter.
I'm using the source code supplied by Derek Eder as a template.
There's a similar question on here however the answer doesn't cover my issue.

```
<h4>Vacancy Selection</h4>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-6'>
            <ul class='inputs-list unstyled'>
                <li>
                    <label class='checkbox inline'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='cbTypeVacant1' />
                    <span class='filter-box filter-green'></span>
                    Vacant
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class='checkbox inline'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='cbTypeVacant2' />
                    <span class='filter-box filter-red'></span>
                    Occupied
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

As defined in my index.html

```
//-----custom filters-----
        var type_column = "'Type Vacant'";
        var searchType = type_column + " IN (-1,";
        if ( $("#cbTypeVacant1").is(':checked')) searchType += "1,";
        if ( $("#cbTypeVacant2").is(':checked')) searchType += "2,";
        self.whereClause += " AND " + searchType.slice(0, searchType.length - 1) + ")";
    //-----end of custom filters-----
```

And as found in my maps_lib.js

The checkboxes make no changes to my markers, all are displayed regardless of whether the checkboxes are selected or not. Any suggestions?

```
fusionTableId:      "1FMeZBi_NYNqAV2Bnf7MdiL1eUlC3zbOg9vpXFxea",
        googleApiKey:       "AIzaSyC8hYnLrg5zUvWEx5klDHe_q8gmgxPiIiI"
```

Not sure how to check if my Api is specific to Fusion Tables?

A JS Fiddle containing the project:
https://jsfiddle.net/yqmn2brw/

Comment: From looking into it further, it seems to be my Fusion Table API. Perhaps something to do with the credentials?
I can't seem to set up the API correctly

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip Not sure what else I need to include on this? Everything else works except for the filters

Comment: Can you reproduce and debug the issue with the information posted?

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry I'm pretty new to JS so I'm not really sure where the issue is! I've posted a JSfiddle that contains the majority of the code but I think the issue lies in the above sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also  modify the name  of the `locationColumn` (the default is `geometry`, but in your table                      it seems  to be `Latitude`)

There  should be  a        notification  about that in the console.

Comment: Yeh, my locationColumn is set to be Latitude in index.html

Comment: So provide a demo  of  your  current implementation. With the mentioned modifications the  filtering works well for me(112              vacant,1480 occupied)

Comment: Sorry not sure if I've done this right, but hopefully it works! https://jsfiddle.net/yqmn2brw/

Comment: column-names  are  case-sensitive(`latitude` !=  `Latitude`)

Comment: Holy F****** S*** you legend! Thank you, it now works :D :D

Comment: Where/How do you get a console notification? I'm using Notepad ++

Comment: @Berry this ins´t provided by your IDE, it´s in your browser. Chrome F12 for example. It must take years to find an error without knowing about the console oO :D